# Jxl can't import Label

Tags: java, excel, jxl, jexcelapi, jxls

I want to write Excel file by add cell to worksheet. but Label doesn't work and show this message "The import jxl.write.Label collides with another import statement" How to resolve this problem?

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.*;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;
  WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
  WritableSheet write = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
    Label label = new Label(0, 0, "Hello");
    write.addCell(label);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must write and close :

```
write.write();

//and

write.close();
workbook.close();
```

Comment: I think a good answer needs more explanation...
And the answer doesn't reference on "The import jxl.write.Label collides with another import statement"